# What is the Goods Station referred to in Scotland Yard

Tags: history, scotland-yard

I'm playing the 1996 version of Scotland Yard.

By 174 on the map is Goods Station. I can't find any reference to this in historical London geography.

Was this a real place? If not, what does it refer to?

Answer (score 5):

I believe it might refer to Bishopsgate, it was used as a goods (freight) station, near Shoreditch in Londons East End. ( I'm an old Cockney.)

Answer (score 0):

It's close to where modern Bermondsey station would be but appears as a terminus rather than a through station. Can't be Bishopsgate which would be north of the river.

Couldn't find anything online about a goods station in South London so nothing more I can add